# Unable to insert image using wrapfigure

Tags: graphics, floats, positioning, wrapfigure, figure-placement

I am trying to add an image to my document (`\documentclass[english]{report}`).

This is what I wrote:

```
\documentclass[english]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{The ACR evaluation table}
\label{fig:crea-alb-scale}
\end{wrapfigure}
\end{document}
```

The image is simply not there. The wrapping works fine, but there is no image or caption. It's not anywhere else in the document either. I tried changing the width, using different image formats, and different placement arguments. I also tried using `\begin{center}`-`\end{center}` or no centering at all. The image doesn't seem to be too big or too small. I read that this kind of issue can occur when the figure is too close to the top or bottom of the page, but I haven't managed to move it. I tried just moving it around in the code and I tried different placement arguments for wrapfigure. What else should I try?

Comment: Either you copied the example incompletely or the file name of the graphic wrong or you ended the argument with ] rather than }.

Comment: i copied everything right. the name is correct, and i tried different images, none of them work. no errors are raised when compiling

Comment: how are you running latex, latex/dvips can not include png

Comment: i tried other image types, other images and example images. nothing works unfortunately.

Comment: Show your log file ...

Comment: Your MWE works fine for me.  It works even better if you add text (lipsum).  One possibility is that you keep seeing the same (wrong) pdf, although that generally involves errors preventing the new pdf from being created.

Answer (score 2):

There is no optional argument `[h]` for `wrapfigure`:

```
\documentclass[english]{report}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{Pictures/crea-alb-scale.png}
    \caption{The ACR evaluation table}
    \label{fig:crea-alb-scale}
\end{wrapfigure}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you. this works fine on a separate test document, but for some reason when I copy all of the same lines to my original document, it doesn't work.

Comment: "it doesn't work"  is not. a useful description ... Is there an error? Is the image missing? ...

Comment: sorry, you are right. no error is raised. nothing appears in the log file. the image is missing.

Comment: Show the log file and everything will be clear!

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, please always post a fully self-contained example. I have amended your code, like so:

```
\documentclass[english]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{The ACR evaluation table}
\label{fig:crea-alb-scale}
\end{wrapfigure}
\end{document}
```

Does that work for you? In that case, try changing `example-image-b` as desired. Leave out the suffix (.png), and pay special attention to the path.

[image]

Comment: thank you for the answer. i will make sure to add those lines to my future questions. no, this does not work. i have tried leaving out the suffix. i also use autofill when adding the image, so i dont think the path is wrong. also, i tried it with different images, and none of them work. regular figures without wrapping work fine.

Comment: Did you copy & paste & try to run my example, exactly as written? `example-image-b` should come with your LaTeX distribution and is to be used as is. If my code does not compile, please take a look at the log file and let us know what the error was.

Comment: yes, i did. as i stated above, everything works fine on a different test file, but doesn't work in my original file. I am not sure what to look for to fix this, because no errors are raised when I compile the file.

Comment: There must be some in the log file. It also means that you haven't shown us all of your code, which makes it hard to debug.

Comment: I cannot share the full code due to confidentiality. But there is nothing in the log file related to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed by moving the image in a completely different place in the code. I had tried moving it before, but I guess I didn't move it far enough.